# App's feitos com Swift funcionam em um iPhone 4 com iOS 7?

Tags: swift, apple, iphone, ios

Cenário:

Um iPhone 4 operando com iOS 7 consegue executar app's desenvolvidos com Swift?

OBS: Não estou me referindo ao 4S, somente ao 4.

Comment: Requisitos do Swift: **iOS 7** e **OS X Mavericks**. Como o iPhone 4 tem suporte ao iOS 7 a resposta é **sim**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, a Apple garante o funcionamento de aplicações escritas em Swift para qualquer dispositivo rodando iOS 7 ou posterior e OS X 10.9 ou posterior.